# loopback XML response array renders as individual entries

Tags: xml, node.js, loopbackjs

I want to return a list of countries as part of my XML API built on loopback.js framework. I'm building an array of country objects and then assign it to response object

```
        var regions=[];
        for (var index in data.regions)
        {
            var country=data.regions[index];
            regions.push({country:{
                    code:country.code,
                    name:country.name
                }
            });
        }
        result.restricted_countries=regions;
```

when I dump the result the array looks fine

```
[ { country: { code: 'AE', name: 'United Arab Emirates' } },
  { country: { code: 'AF', name: 'Afghanistan' } } ]
```

however when I render the result as XML, each country is wrapped into it's own restricted_country node

```
<restricted_countries>
    <country>
        <code>AE</code>
        <name>United Arab Emirates</name>
    </country>
</restricted_countries>
<restricted_countries>
    <country>
        <code>AF</code>
        <name>Afghanistan</name>
    </country>
</restricted_countries>
```

obviously I expected it to be

```
<restricted_countries>
    <country>
        <code>AE</code>
        <name>United Arab Emirates</name>
    </country>
    <country>
        <code>AF</code>
        <name>Afghanistan</name>
    </country>
</restricted_countries>
```

when I change the response type to JSON it works as expected.

I'm using loopback's default XML renderer, just setting `"rest": {"xml": true}` in the config. I'm not sure which library it uses internally and if it's possible to configure it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Got rid of wrapper `country` key in regions array like this

```
regions.push({
    code:country.code,
    name:country.name
});
```

and added it as base for result

```
result.restricted_countries={country:regions};
```

this makes a not too logical JS object but renders an expected XML. not sure if I just fixed the bug or introduced another one but still..